# Find corner points of a cube that has a random point in a 3D grid

Tags: c++, vector, grid, cube, coordinate

I have coordinates (x,y,z) for a evenly spaced 3D grid. Given a random 3D point (x,y,z) somewhere on the grid, how to find which cube has the point. I need to know the 8 corners of the cube.
I have the grid point data in a list of vectors in c++.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming equal length for the grid cubes in all dimentions, you can get the coordinate closest to ohe origo by calculating

```
gx = x - x%l;
gy = y - y%l;
gz = z - z%l;
```

Where `gx`, `gy`, `gz` are the grid cube coordinates closest to the origo (I'm assuming `x`,`y`,`z`>=0 here), `%` is the modulus operator and `l` is the length of the grid cubes.

Note: You can perform the calculations this way as well: `gx = static_cast<int>(x)/l*l;` (`static_cast<>` to account for non-integer `x`)

Then the 8 corners of the grid cube `(x, y, z)` falls into are:

```
(gx, gy, gz)
(gx+l, gy, gz)
(gx, gy+l, gz)
(gx, gy, gz+l)
(gx+l, gy+l, gz)
(gx+l, gy, gz+l)
(gx, gy+l, gz+l)
(gx+l, gy+l, gz+l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the origin of the grid is at `(0,0,0)`, you should divide `(x,y,z)` by the grid's size.
Then you should round the result and multiply it by the grid's size, that is:

```
(nx, ny, nz) = [(x,y,z) / grid_size] * grid_size
```

where `[x]` is the greatest integer `n`, so that `n<=x` (in practice, you should just cast the result of floating-point operation to an `int`). The points you're searching for are:

```
(nx, ny, nz)
(nx+grid_size, ny, nz)
(nx, ny+grid_size, nz)
(nx, ny, nz+grid_size)
(nx+grid_size, ny+grid_size, nz)
(nx+grid_size, ny, nz+grid_size)
(nx, ny+grid_size, nz+grid_size)
(nx+grid_size, ny+grid_size, nz+grid_size)
```